# Operators are missing in the output

Tags: c, data-structures

I was making a **C** program to convert infix expression to postfix expression in which unwanted symbols are showing instead of operators
The output is like `abc@#$^` for input `(a+b+c)`.

I am hereby attaching the code

```
//to convert infix expression to postfix expression
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void push(char);
char pop();
int is_operator(char);
int precedence(char);
char stack[100];
int top=-1;

void main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,count;
    char infix[100],item,x;
    char postfix[100];
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter Infix String");
    gets(infix);
    count= strlen(infix);

    for(i=0;i!=count;i++){
        item=infix[i];
        if(item=='('){
            push(item);
        }
        else if((item>='A'&& item<='Z')||(item>='a' && item<='z')){
            postfix[j]=item;
            j++;
        }else if(is_operator(item)==1){
            x=pop();
            if(precedence(x)>precedence(item)){
                postfix[j]=x;
                j++;
            }
            else{
                push(item);
            }
        }else if(item==')'){
            char a;
            a=pop();
            while(a!='('){
                postfix[j]=a;
                a=pop();
            }
        }else{
            printf("Invalid Expression");
        }
    }
    postfix[j]='\0';
    printf("Postfix Expression\n");
    puts(postfix);
    getch();
}

void push(char a)
{
    char y;
    y=a;    
    top++;
    stack[top]=y;
}

char pop()
{
    char ch;
    ch=stack[top];
    top--;
    return(ch);
}

int is_operator(char i)
{
    if(i=='+'||i=='-'||i=='/'||i=='*'||i=='%'){
        return(1);    
    }else{
        return(0);
    }
}

int precedence(char c)
{
    if(c=='/'||c=='*'||c=='%'){    
        return(2);
    }else if(c=='+'||c=='-'){    
        return(1);
    }else{
        return(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the output is supposed to be? (edit)

Comment: yes I know the output should be ab+c+

Comment: Are you terminating the postfix string with '\0' character? Because, I think that's where the problem is!

Comment: Thanks @kiner_shah the problem is somewhat solved but now the output is coming ab So please help!!!!

Comment: BTW, `gets()` is [dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) to the point of not being part of C standard any more.

Comment: `gets()` is inviting trouble, change it with `fgets()` instead,

Comment: Use scanf("%s",infix) instead of gets(infix). even fgets() is dangerous @sjsam, one can use fscanf() in that case.